# jquery fadeout, load, fadein

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I am using JQuery and what I want to happen is.

Div fades out using the fadeOut command.  It then loads content from a url using the load command.  Then once content loaded it fades back in using the fadeIn command.

The code I have is:

```
$("#myDiv").fadeOut().load('www.someurl.com').fadeIn()
```

However this does not work. It kind of flashes then loads out then loads in.  I think the problem is that the fading is happening before the load is complete.

What should I do

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) callback function like this:

```
$("#myDiv").fadeOut().load("www.someurl.com", function(response, status, xhr) {
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

you might want to use the status of the load() call to see if everything was completed properly.

```
$("#myDiv").fadeOut().load("www.someurl.com", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        // handle error
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this because the "load" is async and the other actions will continue to work?  Your answer will wait to call "fadeIn" after load reports it is done, correct?

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#myDiv").fadeOut(1000, function () {
    $("#myDiv").load("www.someurl.com", {limit: 25}, function(){
        $("#myDiv").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

The limit specifies how long time to wait for an answer in the load call

Answer (score 5):

Use the `success` callback for [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), like this:

```
$("#myDiv").fadeOut().load('www.someurl.com', function() {
  $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do the fading in the load callback function due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX.