# How can I get jQuery html() load complete before fadeIn?

Tags: jquery, html

i use this script to load content of some div, inside another div:

```
$(function() {
        $('#menu a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var h = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#aqui').hmtl($(h).html()).fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
            //alert(h);
        });
    });
```

But, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/8rB3S/, the content is load before `fadeOut()` effect.

i try this tip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745494/588842, but with `.html()`, and this not work.... this only `fadeOut` and dont `fadeIn`

Something like that: `$('#aqui').fadeOut('slow').hmtl($(h).html, function(){$(this).fadeIn('slow');})`

Comment: You have a typo. Rename 'hmtl()' to 'html()'.

Comment: What is the desired effect? May be this >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/8rB3S/1/ <<

Comment: yeah.. i see that typo .. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is synchronous, passing it a callback function will not do anything.

[fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), on the other hand, is asynchronous. So, call it first and provide a callback function that modifies the markup, then fades the element back in:

```
$("#aqui").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).html($(h).html()).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: perfect! is that the effect i want!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the desired effect, but try below code,

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/skram/8rB3S/2/

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var h = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#here').fadeOut(100, function () {
            $(this).html($(h).html())           
           .fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

or

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/8rB3S/1/ (used `#here` as that seems to be where you wanted it)

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var h = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#aqui')
           .hide()
           .html($(h).html())           
           .fadeIn('slow');        
    });
});
```

Comment: the effect i want is that @Frédéric Hamidi answers! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use the callback in fadeout fadein functions :

```
$(function() {
        $('#menu a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var h = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#aqui').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $(this).html($(h).html());
                $(this).fadeIn('slow');
            }):
        });
});
```